# Identifying valve in a flat

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, gas, valve

I would like to know what is this valve for? I'm guessing it may be water, is that right? The valve is located in a flat in the wall.

[image: valve zoom]

### side question

Shall I move it from time to time so it doesn't get stuck? I was told it may happen.

Comment: Another highly improbable use is for a sprinkler system. Although I'm sure if there was one installed it wouldn't have a shut-off valve.  (just plucking at straws, I am.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the valve handle is any indication for what its' function may be, than there is a very likely chance that it is a shut-off valve for: A. water supply (for flat above?) or B. sprinkler system (not likely).

The valve type is either a "gate" or a "globe". Either of them are designed to control water (liquid or vapor) flow. Additionally both valve's have a poor reputation in that the valve stem can break off from the gate or globe (the section that closes the opening to stop flow). It would be wise to first ascertain what the valve is controlling before it is opened or closed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would it be a common practice to install a water valve in a flat for a flat above?

Comment: Probably? Not likely. Possibly? It could happen.  Is the pipe or valve body warm to the touch? That would indicate heated water or steam.

Comment: I checked, it's cold.

Comment: If the valve and what it controls must be known ,  I would say the water heater is a good place to start. Even though the valve handle is in an accessible location use caution when operating it! If it is closed check to ensure all water faucets and appliances are receiving a supply of water. If the valve opens be aware of any sounds of running water and/or check that any tap or spigot previously not with water, is now flowing.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful input; there is no emergency. I was just curious in case at some point in future I've to make use of it and close the water supply but it's rather unlikely.